# if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] on smarty template .tpl

Tags: php, smarty

I usually use php to show some code on spesific domain like this

```
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'myexamdomain.com') {
     ...
}
```

How to use that on smarty template .tpl ?

I have try like this but it does not work.

```
    {if $smarty.server.HTTP_HOST == "myexamdomain.com"}
    ...
    {/if}
```

Comment: {$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST} should works! check {$smarty.server|var_dump}

Answer (score 0):

Please use code like this:

```
{if $smarty.server.HTTP_HOST == "myexamdomain.com"}
   ...
{/if}
```